# Angular controller issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb

I am triyng to reach a simple app that return result from a MongoDB
I am getting this error in the console;

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'controller' of undefined
    at model.js:8**

```
'use strict';

var mid = angular.module('mid', [
  'ngRoute'
]).


    mid.controller('pageCtrl', function($scope, $http){ <------- This line
      $scope.pages = [];

      $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1/pages'
      })
        .then(function(pages) {
          $scope.pages = pages.data;
       })
        .catch(function(errRes) {
          // Handle errRess
      });
    });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: remove `.`(dot) and use semicolon  OR remove `mid.` you need to go like Object chaining.

Comment: If you're going to opt to not use `;`s then do it always unless necessary or use them. Don't do both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the **`.`** after declaring module

```
var mid = angular.module('mid', [
  'ngRoute'
])
```

**DEMO**

```js
'use strict';

var mid = angular.module('mid', [])
mid.controller('pageCtrl', function($scope, $http){ 
      $scope.display = "test";
      
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="mid">
<head>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
 </head>
<body ng-controller="pageCtrl">
 
{{display}}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Close, but they need to complete the statement with a `;` or remove the `mid.` for your answer.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils no need

Comment: Thank you removing the dot did it. will accept in 10

Comment: Ewe. Staying consistent would be nice.